# Is there a way to search for images in xcassets image catalogs in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have different images inside different XCAsset folders in Xcode, but there seems to be no way to search for a particular image in one of these folders built into Xcode.

Any Ideas?

Comment: try to use Slender, I'm afraid it is a paid app.

Comment: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/01/19/find-unused-images-in-xcode-project

Comment: Best i've come up with is using finder to search within your project folder